# CMSensorRecorder is not authorised, but I am never prompted to give authorisation?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-motion, watchos-5

I'm making an app that will record user acceleration for a duration on the Apple Watch and send that data to the paired iPhone. I'm using the `CoreMotion` framework to achieve this.

My issue: I've been using a `CMSensorRecorder` object to record the data. This worked for a while, but `CMSensorRecorder.authorizationStatus()` is now "not authorised".

I've had a `NSMotionUsageDescription` in the `info.plist` files of both the watch and phone apps since the beginning. I've removed and re-added these, with no luck.

I recall the app displaying a prompt to allow motion tracking, but can't recreate the ability to display the prompt. Would greatly appreciate any advice on how to enable `CMSensorRecorder` again. Cheers.

My code initialising `CMSensorRecorder`:

```
if CMSensorRecorder.isAccelerometerRecordingAvailable(){
            if CMSensorRecorder.authorizationStatus() == .authorized {
                print("\(Date()): recorder started")
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).sync{
                        self.dateStart = Date()
                        self.recorder.recordAccelerometer(forDuration: self.duration)   
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                print("\(CMSensorRecorder.authorizationStatus())")
                self.xAccLabel.setText("not authorised")
            }
        }
        else {
            print ("Recording not available")
            self.xAccLabel.setText("Not available")
        }
```

Comment: If the prompt has previously been displayed and responded to, you may have turned off permission in the settings app - you need to turn it back on manually. iOS won't prompt the user again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [THIS](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15470) thread for that and there is one answer for that which says:

> I found that the `CMSensorRecorder.isAuthorizedForRecording()` returns
>   `true` only after your app is authorized in `Privacy/Motion` & `Fitness` (on
>   the iPhone). Then to make the app authorized for `Motion` & `Fitenss` I
>   had to access one of the core motion function (like
>   `startActivityUpdatesToQueue` or even `recordAccelerometerForDuration`).
>   After that you just need to confirm on the iPhone and from now on
>   `CMSensorRecorder.isAuthorizedForRecording()` returns `true`.
>
> Still, I can't get any data from the `CMSensorRecroding`. In my case the
>   `accelerometerDataFromDate` function does not return any data - the
>   returned value is always nil. Because it is said elsewhere that it can
>   take up to 3mins for the data to become available, I am doing the
>   following scenario:
>
> 1. I am starting the recoding session with `recordAccelerometerForDuration(30)`. Here I record the current date:
>      `recordingStartDate = NSDate()`.
> 2. I wait more than `3min30s` (keeping the app on the watch active) and after this time I call:
>
>    `accelerometerDataFromDate(NSDate(timeInterval: 10, sinceDate: recordingStartDate), toDate: NSDate(timeInterval: 20, sinceDate: recordingStartDate)`
>
>    As you can see, I making a 10s window within the requested 30s recording frame.
> 3. I get `nil`.
>
> I also tried shorter timeouts, accessing the data immediately, and
>   even activating the accelerometer before calling
>   ecordAccelerometerForDuration. Nothing helps, I still get nil back
>   from `accelerometerDataFromDate`.
>
> I really wonder how you guys are able to get any readings back from
>   the sensor recorder...
>
> Maybe things will get better after September 9.

So for `authorization` I tried `startActivityUpdates` like shown below

```
self.activityManager.startActivityUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main, withHandler: {(data: CMMotionActivity!) -> Void in

})
```

and you need to declare `let activityManager = CMMotionActivityManager()`

And once user allow it `if CMSensorRecorder.authorizationStatus() == .authorized {` will be `true`.